# Parameter estimation of a WSS process

Tags: random-variable, covariance, gaussian-process

As my research revolves around parameter estimation from signals that evolve in time in a random fashion, I am curious to know what features/ retrievals people normally use to determine the parameters of such processes.

The techniques I am familiar with are based on the parametric forms of the covariance or the power spectral density (PSD). For a Gaussian process, using the covariance-based log-likelihoods (as cost functions) is often convenient, and a simple MLE can resolve the parameters (if enough measurements are available).

I am facing some issues with the parameters of a covariance model that are very loosely connected to these kinds of log-likelihood. I have asked about the specific issue that I have in other threads in this and the mathematics forum. As this issue needs dedicated attention, I am now curious to ask for something more fundamental.

Is there anything else people use as a cost function for the WSS process parameter estimation other than the covariance and the PSD?